# C# Accessing another class's properties from current class

Tags: c#

I am really new at this so I hope my question is not silly.

I have a situation like this:

```
Public class ClassName
{

public ClassName(){}

public string Name {get; set;}
public SomeOtherClass class {get; set;} 

}

public class SomeOtherClass ()
{
public int StatusId {get; set;}
public string StatusDesc { get; set;}
}
```

Now both of these classes are in one cs file.
I want to access the properties of SomeOtherClass through ClassName.

How do I do that?

Thanks a bunch.

I think I need to add the controller to be more clear:

This is the controller function:

```
public void UpdateSession(SessionDetails requestModel)
{

    using (Entities tokus = new Entities())
    {

        var sessionDetails = requestModel;


        switch (sessionDetails.ServiceType)
        {
            case "Provider Service":

                var fafa = new ClassName();

            fafa.SessionID = sessionDetails.SessionID;
            fafa.SessionStatusID = sessionDetails.SessionStatus;
            fafa.StartDate = sessionDetails.StartDate;
            fafa.EndDate = sessionDetails.EndDate;
                fafa.class.AttendanceStatusID = sessionDetails.subclassfromSessionDetails.AttendanceStatus;

            UpdateServiceLog(fafa);
```

The last fafa.Providers.AttendanceStatusID = sessionDetails.staff.AttendanceStatus; gives me squigly lines for undefined as the error. why it doesn't recognize this subclass???

And the UpdateServiceLog is the other function that needs ClassName as input.

Comment: You might be better served with an introductory tutorial or course on C#, since as it stands now the code you've posted will not compile (`class` is a reserved word, so the property by that name in your ClassName definition will not compile).

Comment: Your sample code does not compile as-is.  You have parentheses after `public class SomeOtherClass ()` and you have an identifier named `class`. However, it looks like `ClassName` has an instance of `SomeOtherClass` as a property, so you should be able to access its properties through that.  What specifically is the error you are getting?

Comment: What I really trying to do on the big picture is to transfer data from one object to another. I have a function in some other cs file, which acts a s a controller. I am instatiating the class ClassName there, like this var fafa = new ClassName ();

Comment: What I really trying to do on the big picture is to transfer data from one object to another. I have a function in some other cs file, which acts a s a controller. I am instatiating the class ClassName there, like this var fafa = new ClassName (); and then I have some other class that will be transfering it's object properties to my current one. That's because I have another function in that controller that uses ClassName to execute it's statements.  I hope I am clear

Comment: @BrianDriscoll could you please tell me what is this type of property called? I'm talking about those properties which references another class/model

Comment: @ShahriarRahmanZahin Do you mean type as in data type? I ask because from a semantic point of view there is no special name or definition for a property that belongs to another class... it's just a property.

Answer (score 1):

OK, first off I'd like to give a quick overview of the errors in your original code, to help you understand why you're getting the squiggly lines...

```
Public class ClassName  // "Public" needs to be lowercase
{
   public ClassName(){}

   public string Name {get; set;}
   public SomeOtherClass class {get; set;}  // "class" is a reserved word and
                                            // can't be used as a property name.
                                            // You're probably getting a squiggly here.
}

public class SomeOtherClass ()  // A class declaration doesn't end in parentheses
                                // This will give you some more squigglys.
{
   public int StatusId {get; set;}
   public string StatusDesc { get; set;}
}
```

Here's the corrected code:

```
public class ClassName
{
    public ClassName() { }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SomeOtherClass OtherClass {get; set;}
}

public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public string StatusDesc { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use these classes in your controller like this:

```
    switch (sessionDetails.ServiceType)
    {
        case "Provider Service":
           var foo = new ClassName();
           foo.Name = sessionDetails.SessionName;
           foo.OtherClass.StatusId = sessionDetails.subclassfromSessionDetails.SessionStatusId;
           foo.OtherClass.StatusDesc = "Kerfuffle";
           break;
        // More cases here...
    }
```

Please note that I have used the properties you gave in your original code in order to point out the syntax errors. From your controller code it's obvious that you will have different property names (`SessionStatusID`, `StartDate` etc.) eventually. Since I don't know the types of the properties inside `sessionDetails` there may be a type mismatch, so please take the above code purely as an example of the *process* of assigning values.

Comment: Thank you. It is absolutely correct the assignments. I will answer my qs and explain why your approach was what i was trying to do but it just didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A class generally represents a real-world object, such as a "car".  If you have ten cars, then you need ten instances of the car class.  If you use this pattern, you need to create an instance of SomeOtherClass in your first class in order to use it.  You have already done that in your example - you have an instance of SomeOtherClass called "class".  To access one of it's properties, you would say class.StatusID or class.StatusDesc.

```
Public class ClassName
{

    public ClassName(){}

    public string Name {get; set;}
    public SomeOtherClass class {get; set;} 

    public bool SampleMethod() 
    {
        if (class.StatusId == 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

}

public class SomeOtherClass ()
{
    public int StatusId {get; set;}
    public string StatusDesc { get; set;}
}
```

Note that if you have ten variables of type SomeOtherClass, they can all have different StatusId's, just as ten different cars could have ten different colors.  You drill down into the specific instance that you are interested in.

Comment: I would be careful making broad statements like "A class generally represents real-world objects". I don't think this is true, even generally. "Consider a class which represents a car ..." would have been a much better way to present this example. Classes generally represent a logical unit of data and any associated methods used to indirectly act on that data. This unit of data may or may not have any equivalent in the real world (e.g. what is a "Bitmap" in the physical world? What about a "Socket", or a "File Handle"?)

Comment: @Elemental_Pete I would be happy if you could look at my updated qs. I am mapping in my controller. There is the problem. I would be glad for more input regarding my structure of the function in the controller. Thanks

Comment: @Dan - bitmaps typically represent photographs of kittens or naked women in the physical world, sockets are places you make connections (such as an electrical socket), and file handles are the things you grab and pull towards you to get a file out of the cabinet, so all of those have at least metaphorical equivalents in the real world, but point taken.  I was just trying to keep it simple :)

Comment: @froglim - usually you will only see squiggles under one part of that line of code, so that will help you narrow down the issue.  Remember that these names are case sensitive: "MyObject" is not the same as "myobject".  Also, use Visual Studio's intellisense to your advantage: start a new line of code and type fafa. and then wait a second - once you type the dot, VS should list all of fafa's properties.  Use your cursor to go to the one you are looking for.  At that point, your line will be fafa.class - type another dot and it will show all of class's properties...

Comment: @ElementalPete A bitmap is *not* a photograph, it is a collection of bits which could represent anything, not even necessarily an image. A socket is *not* an electrical socket, it is a an OS-dependent identifier used to locate network communication endpoints on the protocol stack. A file handle has nothing to do with pulling or cabinets, it is again an identifier, this time used to locate a file stream in the file descriptor table. The point is, over-simplification leads to more confusion, *especially* for new developers, than just stating the truth from the outset and allowing them to learn.

Answer (score 0):

This is introductory stuff, and I strongly recommend tutorials and browsing the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dn308572.aspx).

You have basically three choices.  You can use the code you already have and check the property this way:

```
var x = new ClassName();
var whatWeWant = x.SomeOtherClass.StatusID;
```

You can do this because it's a `public` property.

In other situations, it's better to `inherit`.  You do that if one class is a subclass of the other (i.e. "Automobile" as the superclass and "Sedan" as the subclass)

```
Public class ClassName : SomeOtherClass
{

public ClassName()
{
public string Name {get; set;}
public SomeOtherClass class {get; set;} 

}

public class SomeOtherClass ()
{
public int StatusId {get; set;}
public string StatusDesc { get; set;}
}
```

And call the property as if it's just a part of ClassName:

```
var x = ClassName.StatusId;
```

Finally, you can declare one to be `static`.  `Static` classes, values, and methods are similar in concept to "`global`".  You don't instantiate them, but you can call them pretty much anywhere. The caveat is that their value persists; if two things call the same `static` property they will get the same value.  If this isn't desired, you need the above methods.

```
Public class ClassName
{

public ClassName()
{
public string Name {get; set;}
public SomeOtherClass class {get; set;} 

     public string GetOtherClass()
     { return SomeOtherClass.StatusDesc; }

}

public static class SomeOtherClass ()
{
public static int StatusId {get; set;}
public static string StatusDesc { get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well after looking at my code better I realized that I had an instance of a List, and therefor my mapping wasn't working.
So, @Kasun Koswattha method is correct if the I had an instance of my class as a property. 
Therefore because it was a List, I had to do this in my controller:

```
TOK_ServiceLog fafa = new TOK_ServiceLog();

 fafa.Providers = sessionDetails.staff.Select(s => new TOK_ServiceLog_Provider()
                {
                    StaffID = s.StaffID,
                    ServiceID = s.ServiceID,
                    AttendanceStatusID = s.AttendanceStatusID,
                    IsSubstituted = s.IsSubstituted,
                    SubstituteStaffID = s.SubstituteStaffID,
                    Comments = s.Comments

                }).ToList();
```

NOte: Both Providers and staff are Lists.
And the rest of the properties were assigned directly:

```
fafa.SessionID = sessionDetails.SessionID;
fafa.SessionStatusID = sessionDetails.SessionStatus;
fafa.StartDate = sessionDetails.StartDate;
fafa.EndDate = sessionDetails.EndDate;
fafa.ServiceName = sessionDetails.ServiceName;
```

Thank you again for all the input.

Answer (score -2):

First you need to create new objects from both classes. Then assign Someotherclass to the property in Classname class. Then you can access properties of SomeotherClass. Please see the below code.

```
var className= new ClassName()
{
 SomeOtherClass=new SomeOtherClass()
};

var statisId=className.SomeOtherClass.StatusId;
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Why Down vote?  Can you explain what is not right in this solution ?

Comment: Well it wasn't me that downvoted you, but right off the bat, SomeOtherClass=new SomeOtherClass() should be changed to class = new SomeOtherClass() so that this would compile, and also the OP wanted to know how to access SomeOtherClass from inside ClassName - this shows how to instantiate both from a third class.  That's enough issues from 2 lines of code to warrant a downvote.